# Help with the Steffensen's method in MATLAB not using Aitken's delta-squared process

Tags: matlab

I am new to MATLAB I have implemented the following code of the [Steffensen's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steffensen%27s_method) but with out using the implementation of the [Aitken's delta-squared process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aitken%27s_delta-squared_process):

```
%Test of Steffesen's Method

function st(x0)

    tol=10^-6; % tolerance
    itmax=1000; % max number of iterations
    itnum=0; % iterations counter


    disp([itnum,x0])
    x1=(f1(x0+f1(x0))-f1(x0))/f1(x0);
    itnum=itnum+1;
    disp([itnum,x1,abs((x0-x1)/x0)])

    while abs((x0-x1)/x0)>tol && itnum<itmax
        x0=x1;
        x1=(f1(x0+f1(x0))-f1(x0))/f1(x0);
        itnum=itnum+1;
        disp([itnum,x1,abs((x0-x1)/x0)])
    end

end


function y=f1(x)
y=x^3+x-3;
end
function y=f2(x)
    y=x-tan(x);
end
```

The thing is that when I want to test it with $f1$ and $x0=1$ it doesn't converge. I get the same problem when I run it with $x0=2$, and I know that the root is in $1.302775637720899$. Can someone help me to fix this mistake please?

> Edition

```
%Test of Steffesen's Method

function st(x0)

    tol=10^-6; % tolerance
    itmax=1000; % max number of iterations
    itnum=0; % iterations counter


    disp([itnum,x0])
    x1=x0-f1(x0)/((f1(x0+f1(x0))-f1(x0))/f1(x0));
    itnum=itnum+1;
    disp([itnum,x1,abs((x0-x1)/x0)])

    while abs((x0-x1)/x0)>tol && itnum<itmax
        x0=x1;
        x1=x0-f1(x0)/((f1(x0+f1(x0))-f1(x0))/f1(x0));
        itnum=itnum+1;
        disp([itnum,x1,abs((x0-x1)/x0)])
    end

end


function y=f1(x)
y=x^3+x-3;
end
function y=f2(x)
    y=x-tan(x);
end
```

and it gives me

st(1)
     0     1

Columns 1 through 2

```
 1.000000000000000e+00     1.500000000000000e+00
```

Column 3

```
 5.000000000000000e-01
```

Columns 1 through 2

```
 2.000000000000000e+00     1.404837430610626e+00
```

Column 3

```
 6.344171292624907e-02
```

Columns 1 through 2

```
 3.000000000000000e+00     1.316105875037959e+00
```

Column 3

```
 6.316144034836793e-02
```

Columns 1 through 2

```
 4.000000000000000e+00     1.249192129475165e+00
```

Column 3

```
 5.084222085161958e-02
```

Columns 1 through 2

```
 5.000000000000000e+00     1.218482688521551e+00
```

Column 3

```
 2.458344095276661e-02
```

Columns 1 through 2

```
 6.000000000000000e+00     1.213521222822721e+00
```

Column 3

```
 4.071839301098271e-03
```

Columns 1 through 2

```
 7.000000000000000e+00     1.213411714510119e+00
```

Column 3

```
 9.024012975056845e-05
```

Columns 1 through 2

```
 8.000000000000000e+00     1.213411662762241e+00
```

Column 3

```
 4.264659465520323e-08
```

Comment: The assignment of x0 and x1 in and before the while loop doesnt seem to follow the recurrence relation in the wiki page yes? Also has it worked in any test cases?

Comment: Yes I have already read wikipedia :), but I don't know where is my mistake :( or why it doesn't converges in any of both cases, l know that with the tangent function should not because the root is not in the interval $[1,2]$ but with the other one should work, let me try with other functions, but I don't know where is my error , Thanks

Comment: You saw that there is a probably working implementation to matlab on the wiki page?

Comment: No, what do you mean with that ? :)

Comment: As I see, (and I havent looked at it for long) your assignment of x1 before and in the while loop doesnt follow the recurrence relation in wikipedia. You seem to be caclulating the denominator $g$. You see you are assigning x1 as a (albeit strange) function of x0, wheras in wikipedia, $x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{g(x_n)}$ which isnt replicated in the code in either computation of x1? Those are the errors i see.

Comment: jajaja yes I have seen that too, give a minute and I edit my post :), for a verification right?

Comment: I mean that there is the matlab code for the method on the wiki page, of course this doesn't answer your question but could help you to implement it correctly and for cross checking

Comment: I have already edited my post I have wrote the recursion correctly this time , I think now it is correct , could you give me your verification please :)? Thanks

Comment: Thats more like it. Converging? Also look at the code in the wiki page. Looks very compact but it'll help with matlab familiarisation :). Also whats f2 doing? Or is it just there for testing purposes?

Comment: There is another edition with the results :)

Comment: I see. Nice one, try using function handles/anonymous functions as well, makes for cuter code. e.g f1 = @(x_in)(x_in.^3+ x_in.^(-3)); and it does exactly the same as the f1 in your code. You can write g in similar way calling f1 just as you have and it makes (at least for me) easier debugging. seperating the maths from the programming so I know where the mistake is.

Comment: Well what is meaning of Sperating ? Thanks

Comment: Is that working? Was expecting to see "iteration number" "latest x1" "absolute error"

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2Bx-3 I think it is working, or there is a mistake :(